# Chrome extension refused to load the script for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to setup firebase database for my chrome extension. However it still refuse to load the script even after I added content_security_policy

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p47z.png)

`"content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",`

`<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-app.js"></script>`
`<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-database.js"></script>`

Comment: same for me- any solution yet?

Comment: i have the same error please have a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78034742/refused-to-load-script-for-clerk-chrome-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify those 2 links in your manifest file under the `"content_security_policy"` property like so:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-app.js https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-database.js https://www.googleapis.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'"`

Comment: 'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase-app.js" in directive 'script-src'.