# I'm getting this error in chrome extension working with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i want to use firebase in my chrome extension but I'm getting this error .
I have added content-security-policy in manifest file  but I'm getting this error.

> Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-app.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

my content-security-policy in my manifest file is this

```js
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'https://apis.google.com/' 'https://www.gstatic.com/*' 'https://*.firebaseio.com' 'https://www.googleapis.com' 'https://ajax.googleapis.com'; object-src 'self';"
  }
```

please help me to solve this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension refused to load the script for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751707/chrome-extension-refused-to-load-the-script-for-firebase)

Comment: i have already tried that but it's not working

Comment: Download the firebase JS files and include them in your extension