# Refused to load script for clerk (Chrome Extension)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, vercel, manifest.json, clerk

I used the build command in React and successfully made a Chrome extension, but as I launched my extension, I got this error.
using Clerk for authentication, and that's where my code failed.
expectation: I want to get my ui as i launch the chrome extension
Note: While in development, it works fine, but it is not working for the Chrome extension
URL in the manifest.json
one thing is clear that I have to add the below url in the manifest.json in version 3 but dont know how

```
'https://excited-trout-38.clerk.accounts.dev/npm/@clerk/clerk-js@4/dist/clerk.browser.js
```

[image: error image]

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "uvault",
  "description": "save your important blogs here.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "64": "icons-64.png",
    "128": "icons-128.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' https://excited-trout-38.clerk.accounts.dev/npm/@clerk/clerk-js@4/dist/clerk.browser.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["https://www.developer.chrome.com/*"],
  "optional_host_permissions": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
  "permissions": ["storage"]
}
```

Comment: It means you're loading it outside of the sandbox context, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/). Alternatively, don't load it from an external server, put it inside the extension and load it as any other packaged script.

Comment: Could you be more specific? please! because it raises doubt: are you referring to Clerk as an external server or my server, which is hosted on the Vercel?

Comment: Anything outside of the extension package is external code, which is disallowed in ManifestV3.

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification. i suppose that i should use manifest v2 . will that gonna be solve my problem ?